# Returning a new structure with fields changed in Julia

Tags: struct, julia, immutability

I have this problem of trying to create a struct which is a new copy of an existing struct with specific fields changed. I know that it is probably possible to achieve through metaprogramming. However, would that be the correct approach here or would I reinvent the wheel?

E.g:

```
struct A
  a
  b
end

var = A(1,2)
var.b  = 4 # This means var = A(1,4)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** Check [Accessors.jl](https://github.com/JuliaObjects/Accessors.jl), the successor to:

[Setfield.jl](https://github.com/jw3126/Setfield.jl) is a package to do exactly that.

Answer (score 3):

I usually go with defining the `struct` with `Base.@kwdef` and then define an outer constructor like

```
Base.@kwdef struct A
  a
  b
end

Base.convert( ::Type{NamedTuple}, a::A ) = NamedTuple{propertynames(a)}(a)

function A( a::A; kwargs... )
    nt = convert(NamedTuple, a)
    nt = merge( nt, kwargs.data )
    return A(;nt...)
end
```

and then you can do

```
var = A(1, 2)
var2 = A(var, b = 4)
```

you could also define `setindex!` to get the syntax you had in the OP, but that would only let you change one field at a time.

Comment: I don't think this works out of the box, on Julia 1.0.4 and Julia 1.4.0: `MethodError: no method matching length(::Person)` . Does this possibly rely on NamedTupleTools being installed?

Comment: you are right. The `NamedTuple` constructor expects an iterable. It would be enough to define `Base.collect` for the new type if you don't want to implement the full iterator interface.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is already something similiar or better implemented, but this works and it does not rely on any metaprogramming:

```
struct A
  a
  b
end

var = A(1,2)

function reinstantiate(old, pairs::Pair...)
    T = typeof(old)
    field_values = [getfield(old, field) for field in fieldnames(T)]
    for pair in pairs
        index = findfirst(fieldnames(T) .== pair.first)
        @assert index != nothing "$(pair.first) is not a field of $(T)"
        field_values[index] = pair.second
    end
    return T(field_values...)
end

var2 = reinstantiate(var, :a=>3, :b=>4)
```